# "Error creating foreign key (check data types)…" but they do match…

Tags: mysql, innodb, constraint, phpmyadmin

I'm getting the following error trying to create a constraint:

> `Error creating foreign key (check data types)`

Problem is… those column data types **do** match.

The target is an `int(10) unsigned NOT NULL` and is the `PRIMARY` column.
The source, in the same table, is an `int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL`, and the constraint I'm trying to create is a simple `ON DELETE RESTRICT, ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

Now, of course the target is `NOT NULL` and the source is `NULL`, but that's entirely intentional and what I need, and I can't see how could this be a problem. I could understand if it was the other way around…

Is this really the problem? Why? How do I solve it, then? I don't want to be forced to insert a value there even when I don't need one, neither I want to enable `NULL` on the `PRIMARY` column, which doesn't make much sense.

What else could be the problem?

Answer (score 5):

It was a bug with phpmyadmin.

When you create a new constraint you usually are allowed to leave its name field blank, and it fills it for you.

This time, for some still unknown reason, this didn't work and gave this unrelated error.

Filling the name field did the trick, and allowed me to create the constraint.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue and happend to see this thread. I have a feeling that the newest version of phpmyadmin doesn't have this bug.

The name for foreign key must be unique. You can create the same constraint with a different name, but you can't create a different constraint with same name. Not even in a different table.

But the error statement remains same:

> Error creating foreign key (check data types)

...and it is misleading.

Comment: Considering the misleading error message this was a pretty hard error to trace for me.

Comment: just when I thought I'd never figure it out! "you can't create a different constraint with same name. **Not even in a different table.**" thanks ;)